# ExpertPDF - How to know page number based on content in HTML

Tags: pdf, pdf-generation

```
Suppose I have a HTML that have some heading & text like:

Heading 1
text......

Heading 2
text.....

Heading 3
text.....
```

Now I have to print this template in PDF, during print out, I have to add index page which actually refer page number with heading. Means print out should be like this.

```
Heading 1 ....... 1 [page number]
Heading 2 ....... 2 
Heading 3 ....... 3 

Heading 1
text......

Heading 2
text.....

Heading 3
text.....
```

So here I want to know, how to know page number based on text in HTML,  like heading 1 belong to which page number & for others.

```
Any suggestion or idea really appreciated.
```

Answer (score 0):

pdfConverter.PdfFooterOptions.PageNumberTextFontSize = 10;
pdfConverter.PdfFooterOptions.ShowPageNumber = true;

Its done inside the body of this method :-

```
private void AddFooter(PdfConverter pdfConverter)
{
string thisPageURL = HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsoluteUri;
string headerAndFooterHtmlUrl = thisPageURL.Substring(0, thisPageURL.LastIndexOf('/')) + "/HeaderAndFooterHtml.htm";

//enable footer
pdfConverter.PdfDocumentOptions.ShowFooter = true;
// set the footer height in points
pdfConverter.PdfFooterOptions.FooterHeight = 60;
//write the page number
pdfConverter.PdfFooterOptions.TextArea = new TextArea(0, 30, "This is page &p; of &P; ",
new System.Drawing.Font(new System.Drawing.FontFamily("Times New Roman"), 10, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point));
pdfConverter.PdfFooterOptions.TextArea.EmbedTextFont = true;
pdfConverter.PdfFooterOptions.TextArea.TextAlign = HorizontalTextAlign.Right;
// set the footer HTML area
pdfConverter.PdfFooterOptions.HtmlToPdfArea = new HtmlToPdfArea(headerAndFooterHtmlUrl);
pdfConverter.PdfFooterOptions.HtmlToPdfArea.EmbedFonts = cbEmbedFonts.Checked;
}
```

See this page for more details
http://www.expertpdf.net/expertpdf-html-to-pdf-converter-headers-and-footers/

Comment: No, I don't want to inject page number in the footer, I want to know page number based on some text in HTML. Like in HTML I have text ABC & I want to know this ABC belong to which page number during printout.

Comment: Hi, try this link https://forums.asp.net/t/1902490.aspx?How+to+set+and+get+ASP+net+MVC+Hidden+Field+values

Answer (score 0):

This is actually a pretty tricky problem which ExpertPDF would have to provide specific functionality to make possible.

My solution (not expertpdf) for this was to calculate the layout of the PDF first, get the text to be used in the index for each page and then calculate the layout of the index page/s. Then I'm able to number the pages (including the index pages) then update the page numbers in the index.. This is the only way to handle template pages which span multiple pages themselves, index text which wraps to take up more than a single line, and indexes which span multiple pages.

Answer (score 0):

Create a TextElement

```
TextElement te = new TextElement(xPos, yPos, width, ""Page &p; of &P;"", footerFont);
footerTemplate.AddElement(te);
```

The library will automatically replace the &p; tokens.